# subscribe observable (as subject)

Tags: angular, rxjs

i have following example code which returns id+1 of it's elements:

**EntitiesService:**

```
  public create(model: Model): Observable<number> {
        var subject = new Subject<number>();
        this.GetAll().subscribe(result => {
            if (result.find(x => x.name == model.name)) {
                return;
            }
            model.id = result[result.length - 1].id + 1;
            EntitiesService.mock.push(model);
            subject.next(model.id);
        })
        return subject.asObservable();
    }
```

and i would like to subscribe it to get last id:

**component:**

```
 createMealType(type: string) {
    return this.EntitiesService.create({
      name: type
    }).subscribe((id) => {
      console.log(id);
    })}
```

but it never goes to console.log while im debugging neither dont do console.log

get all retyurns only of(mock)

```
  public GetAll(): Observable<Model[]> {

        return of(EntitiesService.mock);
    }
```

how should i handle it?

Comment: Well, the value was probably emitted before you had any subscribers. Try replacing the `Subject` with a `BehaviorSubject` instead. Alternatively, you can use `ReplaySubject` with buffer size of 1, or use the `shareReplay` operator (e.g.: `return subject.asObservable().pipe(shareReplay(1))`);

Comment: what does the `GetAll()` function do? Is the callback called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the need for the `Subject` here. You could use the RxJS operators [`filter`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/filter) and [`map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) to accomplish your requirement and return the observable directly from the `create()` function.

I've also replaced the `Array#find` with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function.

```js
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

public create(model: Model): Observable<number> {
  return this.GetAll().pipe(
    filter((result: any) => result.some(x => x.name != model.name)),
    map((result: any) => {
      model.id = result[result.length - 1].id + 1;
      EntitiesService.mock.push(model);
      return model.id;
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: While this definitely looks cleaner, I don't understand why OP's approach would fail due to wrong implementation. It seems more likely to me that the `GetAll()` observable isn't coming back (or coming back immediately, in which case it shouldn't be a observable).

Comment: with this answer it works ;)
GetALL() method returns only of(EntitiesService.mock) so i dont understand too why it is not working

Comment: @MikeS.: I too can't think of a reason. @OP: Is it working with a `ReplaySubject(1)` instead of `Subject` in your original implementation?

Comment: @pawelek91 `Observable.of()` returns immediately (it's not asynchronous). If it was actually asynchronous, you shouldn't be having any problems to start with. Nonetheless, this approach is cleaner anyway ;)